# How to check for value in a form with Vue when there is nog value atribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a form(multiple forms to be exactly) and I need to check every form if the input fields are empty or not. But because I use data binding thru the model I dont use the value attribute so if I want to loop thru all fields it will return empty values.

Is there a way to do this?

```
// template part
<form v-for="questions in data">
    <div v-for="question in questions">
        <input type="text" v-model="forms[question.id]"/>
    </div>
</form>

// js code 
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(form => {
    form.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(input => {
      console.log(input.value);// will return empty

      // some logic will come here to throw a msg when one or more inputs are empty
    })
})
```

Comment: The point of Vue JS is to avoid document.querySelector and all that stuff. Why are you mixing the two? If you are new to Vue, I would suggest trying some of the basic examples.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments you usually dont use "querySelector" in Vue. Vue is a reactive framework, which means that whenever something changes in the reactive data, vue takes care of the rendering for you.

What you should be looking at is to check th `forms` array instead of directly checking the DOM

```js
const hasEmptyInput = forms.some(answer => !!answer);

if (hasEmptyInput) {
  // throw error or show message
}
```